# Xcode error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format with xcode 14.3.1

Tags: react-native, xcode14.3

I am working on a react-native project. When I am trying to open .xcworkspace file in xcode, while building project it giving this error
"The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."
No file name, nothing provided in logs.
I have done pod deintegrate, pod install. Everything works fine. This error is returned when building project in xcode.

Xcode version is 14.3.1
mac M1 chip 13.5.1
I have tried setting Product -> destination -> destination architecture -> rosetta. Still same error, a lot of things i have tried while searching for solution but nothing works. Please help if anyone have any idea on this issue.